# What permissions does Azure Mobile Services use to access an Azure SQL Database with the mssql object?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have set up an Azure Mobile Service (AMS) that's associated with an Azure SQL database, as usual. However, when I try to use a custom api to query another table (NOT a mobile services table) with the custom API `mssql` object, I get a permissions error:

> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin'.

Some things to note:

- I had to drop delete the database and then re-create it with the same name after the mobile service was created.
- Mobile service name is 'abc', and the table I'm trying to access is owned by an 'abc' schema, not dbo. The other table was created from SQL Server Management studio via a standard T-SQL script.

The AMS api script is very basic:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var sql = "select * from abc.TestTable";

    mssql.query(sql, {
        success : function(results) {
            console.log("Results from SQL Query to TestTable:\n"+results);
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);    
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("Error in SQL Query to TestTable:\n"+err);
            response.send(statusCodes.Error,err.message);
        }

    });

};
```

So to my question(s)... what credentials are used by AMS to access the SQL database? How can I change permissions so that the script above just works (as implied by all the docs I've seen!). Or am I stuck with having to pass a connection string as suggested by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835107/can-a-mobile-service-server-script-schedule-access-other-sql-azure-databases).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Mobile Service it generates the SQL Database backend, or connects to an existing SQL database.  When it does this is creates a SQL Login user with a random name.  In your case the user was 'zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin'.  When you dropped and recreated your database you lost this user having access to the database (which I think you already knew).

To determine the permissions that were assigned to the created user I created a new Mobile Service and I then used SQL Management Studio to script the entire database (I modified the scripting options to ensure the permissions would be included in the script).  I then trimmed it down to just what pertained to the user and the schema.  If you already recreated your schema you can skip that part.

```
CREATE USER [zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin] FOR LOGIN [zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[abc]
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO [zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin] AS [dbo]
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin] AS [dbo]
CREATE SCHEMA [abc]
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[abc] TO [zwxABOesblahblahHYzLogin] AS [dbo]
```

From this it looks like the AMS user is granted a login in the database, Connect permissions, create table permissions and then granted control of the schema as DBO.

I test this by dropping a mobile service then recreating it which I think would put us in the same scenario.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Just need to re-establish that login as valid on the new version of the database. Interestingly I had to separately grant permissions to that login to another existing dbo.[] table.

Comment: @MikeWo, so I'm wondering how I can change the password of that auto-created account. I need a developer to access it from SSMS, but I don't want to give them root access to the SQL Server. If I script a change to the password, where in the Mobile Service do I update the credentials so it can still connect?

Comment: @Corgalore If you are needing to just give a dev access I'd create an account specifically just for that with only the permissions it needs and have them use that. I'd not give the dev access to the MobileService login.

Comment: @MikeWo Good tip. I ended up creating a separate Azure SQL Login. Thanks!